# Unknown error, Script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this isn't working? I have checked like 10 times >.<

HTML:

```
        <div id="slider_images">
            <img src="dummyimg.png">
            <img src="dummyimg.png">
        </div>
```

Trying to give an id to each image in #slider_images div...

```
var images  =   $("#slider_images img");
var imgid   =   "1";
images.each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", "image_"+imgid+"");
    imgid++;
});
```

This isn't working, I want to give each image an id, but this isn't happening.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? What happens?

Comment: What's your HTML look like?

Comment: Also define imgid as integer (without "")

Comment: You included HTML that has no `#slider`.

Comment: @Teemu no, its an id div

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rYCUK/

Comment: @Sparky eh? the problem is with slider_images not with slider div

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: Why put `var slider = $("#slider");` in your jQuery when there is no `#slider` in your HTML?  Clean up the question.

Comment: @Waleed See the fiddle I posted in my comment. The code you posted works fine, so the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: One more ghost error, OP's code is working well in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxGSA/), just like in JasonP's fiddle...

Comment: look here: http://i.minus.com/ibeAnxH2FdXl9E.png

Comment: Construct a jsFiddle and inspect the DOM.  Or just inspect the DOM here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rYCUK/1/

Comment: That doesn't look an `Unknown error` to me ; ).

Comment: @Teemu do you have solution?

Comment: Are you sure the code is executing? Try putting an `alert()` or `console.log()` right above (or inside) `images.each`

Comment: Please don't whine about downvotes.  Nobody thinks you're lying, but if you would simply look at the jsFiddles and/or construct your own, you'll see that the problem is not reproducible with the code as you've provided.

Comment: @Waleed You should never ignore an error message, since if it's there, it has stopped the script execution. You need to fix the error source of this "known error" before trying to solve the problems it's (possibly) causing.

Comment: @JasonP The code is executing, I already checked by puttin an alert in it

Comment: @Teemu and How do I solve a web browser problem?

Comment: Actually I was talking about `Error in event handler for undefined...`-error. In you header you say: "Unknown error", but that doesn't seem to be unknown... This error stops the script execution at some point. You've seen the code you posted working in several fiddles provided by comments here. Once again: the code you've posted here, is not a causing your page fail, it's something else.. Btw, please put the `alert()` _inside_ the `each()`, if `images.length === 0` the `each` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually according to [jQuery.each doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) the callback is called with index and value(DOM), so you can do this:

```
$("#slider_images img").each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).attr("id", "image_" + i);
});
```

Comment: check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wtRjp/), you can use inspector to see id-s are set

Comment: the problem is probably that the javascript error stops javascript execution and the code that sets ids is not even run

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to wrap your code in

```
$(function() {
    //..code here..

});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Tested it locally and it works.  Are there other scripts on the page? If so, try removing them to see if one is causing a conflict.  Also, make sure you're including the jquery library (before calling your script) and make sure you're putting all your code inside `$(document).ready()`. I've made those silly mistakes before...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

imgd is a string, change it to a number. The increment doesn't work on strings.
`var imgid   =   1;`

Comment: Could probably also note that the trailing `+""` is useless (in OP's code).

Comment: Increment does work on strings, http://testingscripts.gofreeserve.com/slider/slider.js

Comment: This Would not change anything

Comment: @Connor that link is an old project done by me, but this time it isn't working :\ whats wrong?

Comment: @DanielPaulSearles Actually I said that

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not find testingscripts.gofreeserve.com

Comment: @Connor I shared /slider/slider.js

Answer (score -1):

Try targeting the parent, thus `#slider_images` only not the `img` inside as well.

So try changing

`var images  =   $("#slider_images img");`

to

`var images  =   $("#slider_images");`

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to do ?